# Adding Z dimension to 2D postgis table

Tags: qgis, postgis

Is it possible to add a z dimension to an existing 2d postgis table for future records without having to create a new table?

Answer (score 1):

Use this for changing the geometry type into POINT Z and updating existing XY points into XYZ points.

```
ALTER TABLE d2d ALTER COLUMN geom type geometry(pointz) USING  ST_Force3D(geom);
```